# Javascript - Returning a value from google map click listener event

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have integrated the 'overlapping marker spiderfier'

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.js

However I am trying to get a value upon click. Here is my initialized code.

```
oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) 
{
     console.log("Hello")
}
```

The code above currently works in this order to my knowledge.

1) On click, it passes the marker and event to the source file.

2) All clustered marker within the set radius will split

3) Click on the separated marker and it loads "Hello"

---

What I want is.

1) Invoke a click event on load and passes the marker and event to the source file -> Clustered marker within the set radius will split (OnLoad)

2) Click on the separated marker and it loads "Hello"

Comment: can't you put a `return a+b;` in `function add` instead of `console.log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood, but something like this should do the trick :

One.js

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var calc = new calculator();
console.log(calc.add(a, b));
```

Two.js

```
this['calculator'] = (function() {
      function add(a, b) {
           return a+b;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

two.js:

```
this['calculator'] = (function() {
      function add(a, b) {
           return a+b;
      }
});
```

one.js:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var calc = new calculator();
console.log(calc.add(a,b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just return calculation result inside the add function

one.js

```
 var a = 1;
 var b = 2;

 var calc = new calculator();
 var result = calc.add(a, b);
 console.log(result); // print result here
```

two.js

```
 this['calculator'] = (function() {

      function add(a, b) {
           return a + b;
      }
 }
```

Comment: this is the simplest and most common

there are many ways to do something like these

1. callback function > https://www.google.co.th/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20callback

2. promise > http://bluebirdjs.com/

Comment: thanks, is it possible for you to start a chatroom with me as I would like to check with you on my methods of passing parameters

Comment: @YubinQiu, i think you can post your idea and your code in this thread and then i and everyone can provide some feedback to you.